# equals sign after a decrement operator in C++ code

Tags: python, c++, decrement

I have trying to translate code from C++ to python and on one line(in for loop), I have:

```
x -= (t = u/1.0+ MIN(c, EPS))
```

I want to know what the '=' sign after a decrement indicates? how can I translate this line in python

thank u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In c assigments are functions at there own, in Python assignments are expressions.
In python this means

```
t = u/1.0 + min(c, EPS)
x -= t  # same as x = x - t
```

Comment: Note that as there's no `MIN` built-in function in C, we can only guess what programmer did put in it :)

Comment: Note that assignments are also expressions in C++ (and I guess in C too.)

Comment: Although with operator overloading what looks like an assignment may actually be a function call in C++...

Comment: @Darryl It is still assignment.

Comment: It doesn't have to be.  It would be really poor form, but my overloaded assignment operator doesn't have to actually assign anything, nor does it need to return a value.  But we're straying off topic.

Comment: @Darryl It is still an assignment expression. It is part of the grammar, whether or not it follows the expected semantics.

Comment: Here's my point.  If this works - `b=a; c=b;` - does that always mean this works - `c=(b=a)`?  The answer is no.  If the assignment operator for b=a is defined as `void operator=`, it won't even compile.